# Symfony move_uploaded_file to public resources?

Tags: php, symfony

Im trying to perform a file upload and am having truble generating a route to tell the `move_uploaded_file` where to move the file. In my routing file (from within the bundle) i have:

```
endorsement_pics:
    pattern:  /images
    defaults: { _resource: EndorseMeEndorsementBundle/Resources/public/images/endorsement_images }
```

And i do:

```
        $url = $this->get('router')->generate('endorsement_pics');
```

Which generates the literal url www.example.com/endorsement/images

And the function

```
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['endorsement_image']['tmp_name'], $url."image1.jpg");
```

Which gives me the error:

```
                Warning: move_uploaded_file(/newsite/web/app_dev.php/endorsement/imagesimage1.jpg) [&lt;a href=&#039;function.move-uploaded-file&#039;&gt;function.move-uploaded-file&lt;/a&gt;]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/24/9254124/html/newsite/src/EndorseMe/EndorsementBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 20
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you won't be able to do it so, at least in dev mode. that path wont get processed thought `RewriteRule` and thus will be invalid. :-/ Apart from that, is there any particular reason why you decided to write to "public resources" directory? In my opinion that's a bad practice - you should only write to `/web` or it's subdirs (although "public resources" is accessible though `/web` but that's different story)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't move a file to a URL — it has to be a filesystem path. Using routes for this is wrong.

To upload a file to the public `web` folder, you could do the following. First, create a parameter in `parameters.yml` for the upload directory path:

```
parameters:
    upload_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads
```

Then use the parameter for an upload:

```
$uploadDir = $this->container->getParameter('upload_dir');
move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['endorsement_image']['tmp_name'], 
    $uploadDir . '/image1.jpg'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

some slight modifications:

```
$fileName1 = $_FILES['endorsement_image']['name'];

        move_uploaded_file(
            $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 
            $uploadDir . $fileName1
        );
```

Also, this statement will no longer be supported in Symfony 4. You have to quote it. I found it easier to just give the path.

```
upload_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads


upload_dir: /usr/home/dir/
```

Also, if you make a change to parameters.yml you must also make the change to parameters.yml.dist or composer will remove the entry.